# what's the point of serializing arrays to store them in the db?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, serialization

I see that people store arrays as like:

`a:6:{i:0;s:5:"11148";i:1;s:5:"11149";i:2;s:5:"11150";i:3;s:5:"11153";i:4;s:5:"11152";i:5;s:5:"11160";}`

why can't they just be:

`11148,11149,11150,11153...`

and have sql "Type" be "Array" ?

this way it's shorter and you can change the values directly in the databse without having to alter "s:" or "i:".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've not seen this a whole lot. But it's clearly done for implementation ease. Serializing data allows to store quasi binary data.

Your second example is a `CSV` scheme. This is workable for storing confined string lists. While it's easier to query or even modify within the database, it makes more effort for unmarshalling from/to the database API. Also there is really only limited `list` support anyway. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set

However, true, the serialized data is unneeded in your example. It's only a requirement if you need to store complex or nested array structures. And in such cases the data blob is seldomly accessed or queried within the database.

Comment: How do I store that list of numbers as CSV? Are there any PHP functions for CSV like `in_array()` is for arrays?

Comment: @Alexandra: Well on PHP side you really only have `explode(",",$a)` and `implode(",",$a)`, which have to be applied whenever a DB interchange occours. I'm not sure, but maybe there are ORMs or ActiveRecord implementations which can do that automatically.

Comment: ah so the data is a simple comma-delimited string :) would using explode() be faster than unserialize()?

Comment: Interestingly I do have an `in_array()` alias which can take a `"set,set,set"` list as second parameter in lieu of an array. But PHP itself does not offer that.

Comment: @Alexandra: I think the speed difference is not significant in comparison to the database access. But explode would be faster than unserialize in any case.

Comment: I'll go with explode because I can store a shorter string in the db, and it looks nicer too

Comment: @Alexandra: If it is an option for your data, then definitely. (Besides the comma delimited format, I've also used a `\n` separated string once.)

Answer (score 5):

One thing you can't do with CSV notation (`1,2,3,4`) is represent multi-dimensional arrays.

Neither way is really appropriate though. The data should be normalized into separate related tables. If there's a real need to store serialized data in a database that can't be or doesn't need to be normalized, it should be stored as JSON, which is language independent and smaller.

Answer (score 4):

there is no mysql type array, and the reason is so you can recreate the array easily, if your data was as you showed it not hard but what about a multidimensional array with non numeric keys. Of course this is NOT good db practice in the first place, breaking normilisation

Answer (score 3):

It's because PHP has the serialize() function that takes a PHP array and turns it into a string like the one you quoted above, and then has another function, unserialize(), that takes the array string and converts it back into a PHP array.

This makes it very easy to turn an array into a string when it needs saving in a database and then turn it back into a proper PHP array after you select it from the database later.

See the PHP manual here:
http://php.net/serialize

and:
http://php.net/unserialize

Comment: Thanks, Jonah, it was a lazy copy-paste on my part.

Answer (score 3):

1. Not all DB servers have an array type (mysql being one)
2. if you have a csv list, you have to explode it, or loop over it to recreate the array
3. multi dimensions aren't possible

With serialize and unserialize you are using native php functions that run faster than php based loop constructs etc.  serialize and unserialize are the way to go if you absolutely positively have to store an array in the db (like for sessions).  Otherwise you may want to reconsider your application design to not store php array in the database.  It may cause problems down the road if you try to access the data with a language other than php.