# Select Query is not working as it should work - MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have the data in my database something like this that represents name, its state and types of cases attorney does:

**name:** `new attar`

**states:** `a:2:{i:0;s:13:"Massachusetts";i:1;s:13:"New Hampshire";}`

**cases types** `a:13:{i:0;s:1:"5";i:1;s:1:"7";i:2;s:1:"8";i:3;s:1:"9";i:4;s:2:"10";i:5;s:2:"11";i:6;s:2:"13";i:7;s:2:"14";i:8;s:2:"15";i:9;s:2:"16";i:10;s:2:"17";i:11;s:2:"18";i:12;s:2:"19";}`

**name:** `Kevin    Regan`

**states:** `a:1:{i:0;s:13:"Massachusetts";}`

**cases types** `a:1:{i:0;s:2:"14";}`

**name:** `Matthew  Gendreau`

**states:** `a:2:{i:0;s:13:"Massachusetts";i:1;s:13:"New Hampshire";}`

**cases types** `a:16:{i:0;s:15:"multiselect-all";i:1;s:1:"5";i:2;s:1:"2";i:3;s:1:"7";i:4;s:1:"8";i:5;s:1:"9";i:6;s:2:"10";i:7;s:2:"11";i:8;s:1:"1";i:9;s:2:"13";i:10;s:2:"14";i:11;s:2:"15";i:12;s:2:"16";i:13;s:2:"17";i:14;s:2:"18";i:15;s:2:"19";}`

The Query I am using is:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    `web_attorney`
WHERE
    (
        `at_status` = '1'
        OR (
            `at_status` = '2'
            AND '2015-05-15' NOT BETWEEN `at_inactive_date_from`
            AND `at_inactive_date_to`
            AND `at_inactive_date_from` != ''
            AND `at_inactive_date_to` != ''
        )
    )
AND (
    `at_juris_states` LIKE '%Massachusetts%'
)
AND (
    `at_availability` LIKE '%Friday%'
)
AND (`at_cases` LIKE '%2%')
ORDER BY
    `at_has_mt` ASC
LIMIT 5
```

**Problem:**

I want to fetch records only where `cases type like 2`.

Since I am using like on PHP serialize array so the query does works but the issue is that it always comes up where `cases types not 2 and 2`. Both are coming by this query.

It also picks the attorneys who have `not case type 2`. Like `new attar` does not have `case type 2` in double qoutes `"2"` but in my query he comes up when he don't.

**UPDATE**

Here is the fiddle example:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e4c3c/1

Comment: Can you provide a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)?

Comment: in your example: `new attar` has 2 (not in double quotes). your LIKE is: `LIKE '%2%'` (no double quotes). so you should get `new attar`. So, your LIKE should be: `LIKE '%"2"%'`? Can fix your example or erase the whole `double quotes` reference?

Comment: Here is the fiddle: [http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e4c3c/1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e4c3c/1) @Strawberry

Comment: in the sqlfiddle, iv'e changed the LIKE to: `LIKE '%"2"%'`, and got the results you're looking for. can you take a look?

Comment: Given that you want to perform queries against the data, I just don't understand why you would store it in this way. Why not normalize your design?

Comment: How can I do this then? I mean what are possible solution to do this? @Strawberry

Comment: I didn't store them with commas separated and ideally I have read storing serialize array is better example to do this. @Strawberry

Comment: This is really too broad a topic for SO, but maybe we can give you some pointers. Let's start with the easy bit: `a:2:{i:0;s:13:"Massachusetts";i:1;s:13:"New Hampshire";}` What does each of the components within this string mean?

Comment: Thank you so much for this help.. @Strawberry It means I am storing Massachusetts and New Hampshire from jquery multiselect tag using PHP `serialize($states)`

Comment: But what are `a`, `i`, and `s`?

Comment: `PHP serialize array` creates them automatically as keys and indexes. Like size, keys and element value. @Strawberry We can later use `PHP foreach loop` to get all these values as it is.

Comment: you can see here more of it [http://stackoverflow.com/q/4951573/4353103](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4951573/4353103). @Strawberry

Answer (score 0):

A normalized approach might look something like this:

```
attorneys
attorney_id*, name
          2 , Kevin Regan
          3 , Matthew  Gendreau


attorney_state
attorney_id*, state*
          2 , Massachusetts
          3 , Massachusetts
          3 , New Hampshire

attorney_casetype
attorney_id,casetype
          2,      14
          3,       2 
          3,       7
          3,       8
          3,       9
          3,      10
          3,      11
          3,       1
          3,      13
          3,      14
          3,      15
          3,      16
          3,      17
          3,      18
          3,      19
```

`*` = (component of) PRIMARY KEY

Comment: I have created one single table to did this whole So actually you referring to cut down this whole to 3 tables? correct?

Comment: Yes. If you want to use SQL in an effective manner then you have to normalise your data.